# Google cloud SQL Server connecting from localhost but not from Godaddy Windows hosting ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, cloud

Google cloud SQL Server connecting from localhost but not from Godaddy Windows hosting. I recently created a database instance in Google cloud SQL Server.

From localhost, I am using below connection string in `web.config` and I'm able to connect, but the same code is not working when uploading that to Godaddy Windows hosting.

I get this error :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

My connection string in `web.config`:

```
<add name="xxxxxxx" 
     connectionString="SERVER=xx.xxx.x.xxx;DATABASE=xxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxx;"/>
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you update Firewall options to allow traffic from Godaddy Windows hosting?

Comment: How did you setup connectivity to Cloud SQL when you created the instance? Did you set it up with Public IP and authorize your home IP address?

Comment: Yes, using Public IP. i added my local ip and its working from localhost. but added godaddy ip and thats not working

Comment: Ah finally i have a good news to share. I aded 0.0.0.0/0 in connections under Public ID Authorized network. and my website is working now.
I know this is like wild card, but if i add only IP address of godaddy, its not opening so i need actual range of IP from Godaddy and will try to add that sometime. Good for now. Thank you so much @BartoszPelikan and Gabe weiss. Appreciate this great help.

Comment: How did you get your GoDaddy IP address? Did you follow these instructions from GoDaddy: https://www.godaddy.com/help/find-my-server-ip-address-12071 ?

Comment: @RajeevKumar You must ask connection string that you need to use from Godaddy. Each hosting provider have their own settings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must configure firewall options to allow traffic from Godaddy Windows hosting.

From [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/sql-server/creating-sql-server-instances#gcloud) use this command to update firewall:

```sh
gcloud compute firewall-rules create sql-server-1433 --description "Allow SQL Server access from all sources on port 1433." --allow tcp:1433 --network [NETWORK]
```

- `[NETWORK]` is VPC network name of your instance.

Above command open port for all traffic so you must add `--source-ranges` with IP range of Godaddy Windows hosting to narrow access.

Comment: I dont know about these above commands. Can i do in Cloud GUI anyway? Google documentation is ofcourse not specific, its more confusing for new people like me thats why i posted question here. Anyone know how to do this firewall setting to allow connection from godaddy? Steps please.

Comment: This shouldn't have been accepted as an answer, as it does not answer the problem the OP has. The problem is not the firewall, but that Rajeev didn't configure the authorized network right to connect to Cloud SQL.

Comment: The proof in this is that once an authorized network of 0.0.0.0/0 was added to authorized network, it now works for them. Which shows that authorized networks, and not the firewall, is the culprit.